# Why does Python not thrown an error message sometimes

Tags: python, exception, message

Why is there no error message when I am running the following code?

main.py

```
def main():
    # load config
    envConfig.init()

    # init mongodb
    mongodb.init()

    # start mqtt client
    sensor_data_mqtt_client.listening()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

sensor_data_mqtt_client.py

```
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    logger.info("Connected mqtt with result code:{} ", str(rc))


def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    topic = msg.topic
    incoming_message = json.loads(msg.payload.decode('utf-8'))
    logger.info("message received. topic:{}, message:{}", topic, incoming_message)

    unify_service.update_warning(incoming_message)
    logger.info("updated warning_history")


def connect():
    # envConfig.init()
    evn_config = envConfig.get_config()
    # mongodb.init()

    client = mqtt.Client()
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_message = on_message
    client.username_pw_set(username='admin', password='public')
    client.connect(evn_config['mqtt']['host'], evn_config['mqtt']['port'], 60)
    logger.info('connected to mqtt, host:{}, port:{}', evn_config['mqtt']['host'], str(evn_config['mqtt']['port']))

    return client


def subscribe(client, topic):
    client.subscribe(topic)
    logger.info('subscribed to topic:{}', topic)


def publish(client, topic, message):
    client.publish(topic, message, 0)


def listening():
    client = connect()

    for topic in DeviceType.get_topic_names():
        client.subscribe(topic)
        logger.info('subscribed to topic:{}', topic)

    client.loop_forever()
```

unify_service.py

```
SIZE_LIMIT = 256


def update_warning(sensor_message):
    warning_history_collection = 'warning_history'
    device_name = sensor_message['deviceName']
    device_eui = sensor_message['eui']
    device_type = sensor_message['type']
    device_district = sensor_message['district']
    device_floor = sensor_message['floor']
    device_location = sensor_message['location']

    filter_json = {
        'name': device_name,
        'eui': device_eui,
        'type': device_type,
        'district': device_district,
        'size': {
            '$lt': SIZE_LIMIT
        },
        'day': dateutil.get_today_start()
    }

    current_time = dateutil.get_current_time()
    update_json = {
        '$push': {'records': {'floor': device_floor, 'location': device_location,
                              'warning_time': current_time}},
        '$min': {"first", current_time},
        '$max': {"last", current_time},
        '$inc': {'size': 1}
    }

    mongodb_wrapper.update_one(warning_history_collection, filter_json, update_json, upsert=True)
```

- I made a mistake in unify_service->update_json,
- '$min': {"first", current_time},'$max': {"last", current_time}
- should be
- '$min': {"first": current_time},'$max': {"last": current_time}

When I am running the code, there's a logger message

> message received. topic:xxx, message:xxx

in the console, but no error message is thrown.

How can I make the code throw an error message? Any suggestion is appreciated.

When I call unify_service.update_warning in unit test. It gives error message:

```
FAILED (errors=1)

Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python3.7\lib\unittest\case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "D:\python3.7\lib\unittest\case.py", line 628, in run
    testMethod()
  File "F:\workspaces\PythonWorkspace\unify-service\service\unify_service_test.py", line 13, in test_update_warning
    unify_service.update_warning(sensor_message)
  File "F:\workspaces\PythonWorkspace\unify-service\service\unify_service.py", line 37, in update_warning
    mongodb_wrapper.update_one(warning_history_collection, filter_json, update_json, upsert=True)
  File "F:\workspaces\PythonWorkspace\unify-service\common\mongo\mongodb_wrapper.py", line 20, in update_one
    mongodb.get_db()[collection].update_one(condition, data, upsert)
  File "D:\python3.7\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 1003, in update_one
    session=session),
  File "D:\python3.7\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 856, in _update_retryable
    _update, session)
  File "D:\python3.7\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1492, in _retryable_write
    return self._retry_with_session(retryable, func, s, None)
  File "D:\python3.7\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1385, in _retry_with_session
    return func(session, sock_info, retryable)
  File "D:\python3.7\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 852, in _update
    retryable_write=retryable_write)
  File "D:\python3.7\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 822, in _update
    retryable_write=retryable_write).copy()
  File "D:\python3.7\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 618, in command
    self._raise_connection_failure(error)
  File "D:\python3.7\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 613, in command
    user_fields=user_fields)
  File "D:\python3.7\lib\site-packages\pymongo\network.py", line 129, in command
    codec_options, ctx=compression_ctx)
  File "D:\python3.7\lib\site-packages\pymongo\message.py", line 704, in _op_msg
    flags, command, identifier, docs, check_keys, opts)
bson.errors.InvalidDocument: cannot encode object: {'first', 1594177547129}, of type: <class 'set'>
```

TestUnifyService.py

```
class TestUnifyService(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_update_warning(self):
        envConfig.init()
        mongodb.init()
        sensor_message = {'isAlarm': 'true', 'isDemolition': 'false', 'isLowVoltage': 'false', 'voltage': '3.6', 'applicationName': 'winext-application', 'deviceName': 'seal-01', 'eui': 'ffffff10000118c0', 'type': 'seal', 'district': 'New York', 'floor': '6', 'location': 'New York'}
        unify_service.update_warning(sensor_message)
```

mongodb_wrapper.py

```
def insert_one(collection, data):
    return mongodb.get_db()[collection].insert_one(data)


def insert_many(collection, data):
    mongodb.get_db()[collection].insert_many(data)


def update_one(collection, condition, data, upsert):
    mongodb.get_db()[collection].update_one(condition, data, upsert)


def update_many(collection, condition, data, upsert):
    mongodb.get_db()[collection].update_many(condition, data, upsert)


def find_one(collection, query):
    return mongodb.get_db()[collection].find_one(query)


def find_all(collection):
    return mongodb.get_db()[collection].find()


def find_all_without_id(collection):
    return mongodb.get_db()[collection].find({}, {'_id': False})


def find_all_condition(collection, condition):
    return mongodb.get_db()[collection].find(condition)


def find_all_condition_order(collection, condition, field):
    order = [(field, pymongo.ASCENDING)]
    return mongodb.get_db()[collection].find(condition).sort(order)


def count(collection, condition):
    return mongodb.get_db()[collection].find(condition).count()


def find_all_limit(collection, limit):
    return mongodb.get_db()[collection].find().limit(limit)


def find_with_desc_order(collection, condition, field, limit):
    order = [(field, pymongo.DESCENDING)]
    return mongodb.get_db()[collection].find(condition).sort(order).limit(limit)


def aggregate(collection, pipeline):
    return mongodb.get_db()[collection].aggregate(pipeline)


def remove_all(collection):
    return mongodb.get_db()[collection].delete_many({})


def remove_all_condition(collection, condition):
    return mongodb.get_db()[collection].delete_many(condition)


def remove_one(collection, data):
    return mongodb.get_db()[collection].remove(data)


def create_indexes(collection, tuple_indexes):
    mongodb.get_db()[collection].create_indexes(tuple_indexes)


def create_index(collection, tuple_index):
    mongodb.get_db()[collection].create_index(tuple_index, unique=True)


def get_indexes(collection):
    return mongodb.get_db()[collection].list_indexes()
```

> unitTest.py -> unify_service.update_warning gives error message.

> main.py -> mqtt.on_message -> unify_service.update_warning gives no error message.

> How can I make main.py -> mqtt.on_message -> unify_service.update_warning gives error message? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: When I call unify_service.update_warning in unit test. It gives error message: bson.errors.InvalidDocument: cannot encode object: {'first', 1594177547129}, of type: <class 'set'>     class TestUnifyService(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_update_warning(self):
        envConfig.init()
        mongodb.init()
        sensor_message = {'isAlarm': 'true', 'isDemolition': 'false', 'isLowVoltage': 'false', 'voltage': '3.6', 'applicationName': 'winext-application', 'deviceName': 'seal-01'...}
        unify_service.update_warning(sensor_message)

Comment: It might be a good idea to add that to the question itself by editing it.

Comment: `{1, 2}` creates a [set](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set). You get errors from Python only when there is an attempt to do something that doesn't work; creating wrong data can't cause a problem until it is used.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a `bson.errors.InvalidDocument: cannot encode object: ... of type: <class 'set'>` message it's likely you have accidentally constructed a set rather than a dict, and indeed that is the case.

Your issue is here:

```
'$min': {"first", current_time},
'$max': {"last", current_time},
```

It likely should be:

```
'$min': {"first": current_time},
'$max': {"last": current_time},
```

Comment: Thanks Belly, I've already fixed the issue.
What I confused is that no error message is given while I am running the code above.
But when I run unit test to just test the function unify_service.update_warning, It gives error message.

Comment: Your `update_one()` looks wrong as well. Should it be `mongodb_wrapper.warning_history_collection.update_one(filter_json, update_json, upsert=True)`